# how do i go through an html page using beautiful soup while storing data in a dictionary

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

My html code is of this format:

```
<h3>Head1</h3>
<ul>
    <li><a link></a> data</li>
    <li><a link></a> data</li>
    <li><a link></a> data</li>
</ul>
<h3>Head2</h3>
<ul>
    <li><a link></a> data</li>
    <li><a link></a> data</li>
    <li><a link></a> data</li>
</ul>
.
.
.
```

My question is to create a dictionary of this format:

```
dict = { 
    Head1:data1,
    Head1:data2,
    Head1:data3,
    Head2:data1,
    Head2:data2,
    .
    .
    .
}
```

I'm using Beautiful Soup.

Can anybody help me with sample code?

I only request for the loop.

Cheers!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can not. Dictionaries can't have duplicate keys

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest. You're right. Assume that i have the dictionary part solved (as in i do key1: [data1, data2, data3], ...) how would i write the code. I'm not completely clear with the functions of Beautiful Soup hence I need the code to understand. I tried using a find(element) as the loop condition, but it wouldn't work. So, I'm not really sure where to go...

Comment: update your question with actual html fragment and a valid expected result

Comment: I don't understand, you mean a list of values for each key?
 `some_dict = {'Head1': ['data1', 'data2', 'data3'], 'Head2': ['data1', 'data2', 'data3']}`